how to use sass in the nuxt 3 module in component?
I'm making my ui library. I want to make it a nuxt module. I used sass in the components. When doing "nuxt-module-build" I get an error. I follow the syntax.
 src/runtime/components/Button.vue.sass 111:36  root stylesheet
  async setup (options, nuxt) {
    const resolver = createResolver(import.meta.url)

    await addComponentsDir({
      path: resolver.resolve('./runtime/components'),
      pathPrefix: false,
      prefix: 'Simple',
      global: true
    })
  }

Sass and loader is installed in dependencies
    nuxt.options.css.push(resolver.resolve('./runtime/components/buttons', 'Button.vue'));
    nuxt.options.css.push(resolver.resolve('./runtime/components/buttons', 'Button.vue.sass'));

But I still get the error

Sometimes, clearing the Nuxt cache can help resolve strange build issues.
npx nuxt clean


Try running the build command with verbose logging. You can add --verbose to the build command to get more insight into what's failing.
nuxt build --verbose

